Traveling out of France waiting on first carte de séjour
I'm a US citizen with a 3-month VLS (passeport talent - carte bleue européenne) visa that starts June 1 (so June 1 - August 30) and that I will be able to "validate" and turn into a 4-year titre de séjour upon arrival. I have a trip to Japan towards the end of August, leaving before the VLS expires and arriving after it expires. I will make my request for the carte de séjour immediately on arrival, but it's likely if not guaranteed that I won't get my carte de séjour before the trip.
Is there any way to still go on this trip, or should I cancel?
I saw that there were two options, mainly asking the préfecture for a return visa (rarely seems to be given except if there's a death in the family or something) or applying for some kind of return visa from Japan.

Inside France you still have a pending initial residence permit that allows you (under national law) to remain in France - the Schengen 90 days rule does not apply while in France. As a visa free national, you may enter the Schengen area as a visitor based on your passport alone - that will cover you until you arrive back in France.

I can enter as a visitor, even if that isn't my "goal" (which is to continue working)?

For the other Schengen countries you are a visitor, traveling/transit to France. For France itsself, you are waiting for the inititial residence permit application result.

@bakeneko Ignore Mark's advice, he frequently misunderstands EU law and has no experience in French law. His last comments are mostly irrelevant to the question at hand. Whether you can enter is only part of the question, the main risk is that you have deemed to have abandoned your application, in which case you may not be allowed to lodge a new one without leaving the country and applying for a new visa. I have no idea whether that's likely or not but official advice has always been not to leave the country.

How come your VLS-TS is only valid for three months? I thought they usually issue a one-year visa in your situation.

@Relaxed I am pretty sure it's a basic Long Stay visa and not a VLS-TS (as OP mentions VLS). VLS requires you to go to the prefecture in a two month period to get a the titre de séjour and can't act as a residence permit (unlike a TS one)

@NicolasFormichella True, although it's still odd to get that for a passeport talent, that was my point.
